# Make a parabola steeper at both sides while keeping both ends

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm having a parabola with both axes being from 0 to 1 as follows:

[image]

The parabola is created and normalized with the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# normalize array
def min_max_scale_array(arr):
    arr = np.array(arr)
    return (arr - arr.min())/(arr.max()-arr.min())

x = np.linspace(-50,50,100)
y = x**2

x = min_max_scale_array(x)
y = min_max_scale_array(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
```

I want to create another one with both ends being the same but both sides become steeper like this:

[image]

I thought of joining an exponential curve and its reflection but that would make the resulting parabola looks pointy at the bottom.

Can you show me how to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: All parabolas are different scales of the same thing. Change the scale to get any parabola you want.

Comment: May I ask why you're trying to do this?

Comment: @mozway yes I'm doing this for data augmentation regarding patterns in deep learning. The same curve/parabola but different variations

Comment: @elbashmubarmeg yes I tried changing the scale but then both ends does not remain the same

Comment: should the transformation be only for parabolic curves or any arbitrary curve?

Comment: How about changing the exponent? `y = x ** 4`

Comment: @mozway yes any curve would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify any arbitrary curve, you can change the x values, for example taking a power of it:

```
# x and y are defined

for factor in [1.1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4]:
    x2 = 2*x-1
    x3 = (abs(x2)**(1/factor))*np.sign(x2)/2+0.5
    ax.plot(x3, y, label=f'{factor=}')
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the exponent to get a steeper curve with the same value at the extremes. You need to pick a larger value that is an even integer (odd numbers won't give a parabola).

```
y = x**4
```

[image: y = x**4]

Comment: Note that this only works with integer, even exponents ;)